# What exactly is PDCSAP flux used in kepler missions?

Tags: the-sun, kepler-telescope

I am having trouble finding a good explanation for what PDCSAP flux is. One place it's mentioned is [here](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/tess/LightCurveFile-Object-Tutorial.html). What exactly is PDCSAP flux is in relation to something like the apparent magnitude of a star?

Comment: Can you give a link to a place where you have encountered this terminology?

Comment: https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/docs/tess/LightCurveFile-Object-Tutorial.html

Comment: You spelled it wrong in your question, so that would make it very difficult for people to find.  I'll fix that and edit in the link.

Comment: Sorry, about that, thank you.

Comment: Take a look at pages 130 to 200 of https://archive.stsci.edu/kepler/manuals/KSCI-19081-003-KDPH.pdf  and see if that explains pre-search data conditioning to your satisfaction.

Comment: Okay, I have more information on the PDCSAP flux, but my question still remains. Is this at all similar to the apparent brightness of the star?  Like how does the PDCSAP flux relate to a stars brightness.